# Regex to extract long hexadecimal string

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to extract with a regex the value after ajaxBrowserNavigationCheck('&x and before the = from the following javascript code:

```
if (ajaxBrowserNavigationCheck('&x909ef93d-61ac-4311-ac56-20c2ae9770f5=7ebdc2a4-df58-4c1c-9b50-96964c93e927', '', 'servletcontroller', '')){
    processBrowserNavigationButton();
```

Basicly teh value I want to extra are **&x909ef93d-61ac-4311-ac56-20c2ae9770f5** (the value before the = and we need the &x)
   and **7ebdc2a4-df58-4c1c-9b50-96964c93e927** (the value after the =)

Note that the value is there twice (its after MODE=BROWSER_NAV)
  Note that both value have 36 char without the &x
  the &x is always there for the first string
  My reg ex is a bit rusty here what I got so far:
**(&x([0-9a-fA-F]|-)+)** get me the first part

**(&x([0-9a-fA-F]|-)+)|(=([0-9a-fA-F]|-)+)** get me both but with the = we don't want it...

Edit: Sorry that I forgot the language, it's for a jmeter script which use jakarta ORO.

Edit2: I realize I can split those in two variable or even in three in jmeter that make it a bit easier.

Edit3: I removed the window location part because it was misleading since it was the same in the ajax part. 
in *ajaxBrowserNavigationCheck('&x909ef93d-61ac-4311-ac56-20c2ae9770f5=7ebdc2a4-df58-4c1c-9b50-96964c93e927', '', 'servletcontroller', ''))*
we want **&x909ef93d-61ac-4311-ac56-20c2ae9770f5** and **7ebdc2a4-df58-4c1c-9b50-96964c93e927**

Comment: If you don't want the `=` in your match, use `(?==)` (lookbehinds).

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what language you are using, so it's hard to give a solid answer.

This matches just your targets:

```
&x[a-fA-F0-9-]*(?==)
```

The last term is a *look ahead*, which asserts, but does not capture, an equals sign.

---

This regex matches all the input and captures each target twice as groups 1 and 2:

```
(?m).*?(&x[a-fA-F0-9-]*)=.*(&x[a-fA-F0-9-]*)=.*
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/zbegSAVONL) on rubular

Comment: Thaks, You got the first part right, but it seem to get the rest of the line for the second part. First part = &x[a-fA-F0-9-]* The second part there no &x so I got : =.*([a-fA-F0-9-]*) but I'm still getting what after the string I want (7ebdc2a4-df58-4c1c-9b50-96964c93e927).

Comment: I've added the "multi-line" flag. This works for me when tested (see link in question). Let me know

Comment: ok it seem that I wasn't clear about the part2, I've updated the code that was misleading, the value in the windowloaction variable was the same that was in the first part, what we actually need is the value after the "=" after the value find with the first regex (&x[a-fA-F0-9-]*)

Comment: I got the second part with ((?<==)[^}]*)(.([a-fA-F0-9-])){3} but only work in my web regex (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) not in jmeter. The jmeter regex extractor (ORO) don't like "<" in "((?<==)[^}]*)" that ignore "=" from the whole string.

Comment: Ok I got it: first I get the second part up to servletcontroler with this: =.*([a-fA-F0-9-]*)\'servletcontroller then I extract the first part with (=(.*?)\') jmeter oro allow to get result inside a result so it allowed me to get the value aroudn the = and the quote.